# Is Diffie Hellman not an application of ZKP?

Tags: diffie-hellman, zero-knowledge-proofs

From what I could gather, zero knowledge proof is a way for a prover to convince a verifer of possession of some data without sharing said data. I understood the ali baba cave problem. Diffie Hellman on the other hand seems to be a way for two people to create a shared secret key without explicitly divulging the key itself.

The difference is clear till this point. However, a lot of projects and research papers on ZKP are about sharing the secret, such as email-password authentication with ZKP. In such examples the line between Diffie Hellman and ZKP is blurring since both appear to do the same thing.

Are they the same or not? I'd also appreciate some alternative definitions and explanations of ZKP.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same. Zero-knowledge proofs allow a prover to convince a verifier that they know a certain piece of data without revealing the actual data, while Diffie Hellman key exchange allows two parties to generate a shared secret key without revealing the key to any third party. A Zero-knowledge proof is based on the concept of proving knowledge of Z without revealing the actual Z, instead on Diffie Hellman key exchange is based on the concept of generating a shared secret key without revealing the key itself.